# Image from servlet cant be opened with browser

Tags: java, http, servlets, stream

I am trying to output an image with servlet. This is my code:

```
@WebServlet(name = "PhoneImageServlet", urlPatterns = {"/image/phone"})
public class PhoneImageServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try (InputStream in = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/images/phone.png");
             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
             BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream())) {

            response.setContentType("image/png");

            int ch=0;
            while ((ch=br.read()) != -1) {
                out.write(ch);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this is the result when I try to open the picture with my browser:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtWO7.png)

Do you know what is the problem?

By the way the code works if I use absolute URL to image in my hard drive. The problem started when I moved the image to the .war file.

---------------------- edit -----------------------

I changed my code according to Stephen C's answer and it works now!

```
@Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("image/png");

        try (InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/images/phone.png");
             BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(is);
             BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream())) {

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while ((in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                out.write(buffer);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An image is binary data.  But you are reading it from the resource as characters.  Then you are writing those characters as bytes.  The result is that you are mangling the image.

Read as bytes.  Write as bytes.

Don't use `BufferedReader` or `InputStreamReader`.

Use `BufferedInputStream` instead.

---

A second problem is that you need to call `response.setContentType("image/png")` before you call `response.getOutputStream()`.   Calling `getOutputStream() or`getWriter()` "commits" the response by outputting the response headers.  Changes to the headers (such as the content type) after the response has been committed have no effect.